# send file to the server by postmethod in vb.net and at the server side receiving it and saving it in folder

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

But its not receiving the file

```
Public Sub UploadFile(filePath As String, url As String)         
Using httpClient As New HttpClient             
Using fileStream As New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)                 
Dim fileContent As StreamContent = New StreamContent(fileStream)                 
Dim formContent As MultipartFormDataContent = New MultipartFormDataContent()  
formContent.Add(fileContent, "file", Path.GetFileName(filePath))                 
Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = httpClient.PostAsync(url, formContent).Result
End Using        
End Using   
End Sub
```

have called this method with url and file path

handle that file upload here in cs file like

```
if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")   
{       
if (Request.Files.Count > 0)      
{             HttpFile uploadedFile = Request.Files[0];        
  string fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);       
  string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/uploads/" + fileName);                
  uploadedFile.SaveAs(filePath);       
  }  }
```